# How do I save and restore all the vb6 ide settings?

Tags: ide, vb6

I've seen this tip on [DevX](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18491) which should '*account for most of the Visual Basic IDE settings*'.

Does anyone whether this is sufficient or whether there are more settings out there?

Comment: Note that you seem to need to register with DevX to see the tip.  Here are the registry keys:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\Microsoft Visual Basic
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks pretty complete, however if you have custom Add-Ins this will not get them. I did a quick search of my Add-Ins and I don't see any generic way of backing them up as they have their own registry keys. The **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0** has an Addins sub-folder so if you have custom add-ins you should at least get a message that they can't be found. Otherwise, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and take note of the registry keys and files that are read when you start Visual Basic.

Comment: +1. Those registry keys are documented in this MSDN article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190212 I'd also observe that the tip is by Francesco Balena who is an uber-guru - he wrote one of the biggest selling books on VB6, he is regional director for MSDN Italy, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in these two registry keys:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\Microsoft Visual Basic HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0

Access them by running Regedit.