# How do you copy VB6 user settings/preferences from one PC to another?

Tags: ide, vb6, settings

Where are all of the VB6 user preferences (like custom edits to the toolbar, etc.) stored?

I'd like to copy all of those from an old PC to my new one.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of my question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056176/how-do-i-save-and-restore-all-the-vb6-ide-settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save and restore all the vb6 ide settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056176/how-do-i-save-and-restore-all-the-vb6-ide-settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karl Peterson [posted a tutorial](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/04/06/customizing-the-ride-part-1.aspx) on this last month!.

Essentially you just export everything below the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0` and then import on the new machine.

Comment: Thanks, even more than I was looking for! Karl has some great tips. I didn't realize he was still actively posting.

Comment: Oh yes he is! Well worth keeping an eye on his website what's new page http://vb.mvps.org/news.asp and his Visual Studio magazine column on VB6 http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/List/Classic-VB-Corner.aspx

Comment: ... I posted about Stackoverflow on the VB6 newsgroup, and Karl did join, but I don't think he's hooked. Looks like he hasn't been here since February http://stackoverflow.com/users/121018?tab=activity#tab-top

Answer (score -2):

It depends on each program.

One can chose to save them in an .ini file, others in the registry under HKCU\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings, and any other option that developer thought that it was creative.

Comment: I think the question is about the VB6 IDE.